# error in using Mat type in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

How can I search into a Mat type in opencv to find some spesific value?

This is what I have done until now:

```
Mat L;

for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
    if( L[i][j]> 0){
       Index.push_back(std::make_pair(i,j));
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this the whole code, no `#include` directives at all? And what is the error.

Answer (score 1):

L[i][j] is invalid, as you probably found out already ;)

you have to know the *type* of the Mat to access its elements:

```
Mat L(8,8,CV_8U);
uchar elm = L.at<uchar>(i,j);
```

alternatively, there's

```
Mat_<uchar> L(8,8);
uchar elm = L(i,j);
```

Comment: should I work with that the same as you? since its type is different from yours